# mysql2 gem not installing on CentOS 5.3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, centos5

I'm trying to get the gem mysql2 installed on centOS5.3 but resulting in a conflict to mysql55.

Sometimes (not always) I can install mysql55 and mysql55-server but after that I need to install mysql-devel to get a missing mysql.h file on the gem mysql2 installation.

But mysql-devel conflicts to mysql55 and install fails.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get the following environment up?

rails 3.2
ruby 1.9.3
mysql 5.5
apache + passenger

on CentOS5.3 final machine?

if it doesn't which one you recommend me?

This is my other possibilites:

CentOS 5.5
debian 5.0.6
openSUSE 11.2
Ubuntu 10.04.1
Fedora 12

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried mysql55-devel.  You need the development headers that match the installed server, most likely.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [this thread at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754662/errors-installing-mysql2-gem-via-the-bundler/12067251#12067251) which explains the solution for CentOS. This problem will be fixed if you tweak the commands with regards to your OS and you are able to successfully install the mysql2 gem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the MySQL site for RPMs?

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads

Select "Oracle Linux", which is a RHEL derivative (MySQL is an Oracle product now, so this is just some stupid branding game on their part).  You should see the MySQL, MySQL-shared, MySQL-devel and MySQL-compat packages for x86_64 and i386 architectures.  Try using those.  You may need to uninstall the CentOS default packages.